# How do I replace chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest with declarativeNetRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a Chrome extension I've built to intercept and redirect some assets that are loaded on a page.

To do this, I'm relying on the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` API and it's working fine.

However, Google has announced that it will deprecate this API in 2023 so I'm trying to switch to declarativeNetRequest.

This is my code (`tab` refers to current active tab & I'm omitting the declaration of `redirectionMap`) :

```
// background.js

async function updateAssetRedirectionRules(redirectionMap, tab) {
  // redirectionMap is an array of { originalUrl, newUrl }

  let updatedSessionRules = await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({
    // removing all current rules
    removeRuleIds: redirectionMap.map((_, index) => index + 1),

    addRules: redirectionMap.map(({ originalUrl, newUrl }, index) => {
      return {
        "id": index + 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": { 
          "type": "redirect", 
          "redirect": { 
            "url": newUrl
          } 
        },
        "condition": { 
          "urlFilter": originalUrl, 
          "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"],
          "tabIds": [tab.id] 
        }
      }
    })
  })
  
  // store this session so that I don't reset the rules again for the same tab
  chrome.storage.local.get(['redirectionSession'], ({ redirectionSession }) => {
    redirectionSession = redirectionSession || {}
    redirectionSession[tab.id] = updatedSessionRules
    chrome.storage.local.set({ redirectionSession })
  })
}

// I'm omitting the part where I'm getting the tab.id but I do get it and it's the correct one

chrome.storage.local.get(['redirectionSession'], async ({ redirectionSession }) => {
  if (!redirectionSession || !redirectionSession[tab.id]) {
    await updateAssetRedirectionRules(redirectionMap, tab)

    // refresh the page for the new redirection rules to take effect
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { 
      url: whateverTheCurrentUrlIs 
    })
  } else {
    // my new redirection rules *should* be applied
  }
})
```

In the code above, `updatedSessionRules` is `null` and when I reload the tab, still the original URLs are used when the page fetches its assets.

Is this the correct way to do it ?

Comment: As the announcement/documentation says a normal extension (not installed via policies) has to use declarativeNetRequest API, which can be configured dynamically. Can you add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to your question to show how you use webRequest currently?

Comment: Hi wOxxOm, I didn't know about https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#dynamic-and-session-scoped-rules -  Thank you, I will take a look and if it doesn't helps my use case, I'll get back to you. If it does solve my problem, you could turn your comment into an answer. :-)

Comment: If I can configure this dynamically, how can I do it so that the rules are updated, dynamically, BUT before the first request for an assert goes out ? Oh I guess I could do it inside chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate() ?

Comment: Please see my updated OP :)

Comment: You probably want to apply the rules only to this specific tab, in which case use updateSesssionRules which allows specifying `tabIds`  inside the rule's condition. As for timing, it depends on how this tab is navigated. If you control it then first create an empty tab `about:blank`, await updateSessionRules, then navigate the tab via chrome.tabs.update. Note that you should wait for the API, so to fix your code add `return` before chrome.declarativeNetRequest call and `await` before updateAssetRedirectionRules, as well as `async` before the get's callback.

Comment: Thank you! I will update and see what I get and let you know to turns this into an answer.

Comment: It's not working. I don't know if it matters but in the code above `updatedSessionRules` is `null` but no errors are thrown. After the tab is reloaded, still the original URLs are used. In terms of navigation, like I said, tab loads, I update the session rules and then I reload the tab, so using `about:blank` seems unnecessary.

Comment: It works! I had hardcoded `"resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]` but I should instead use `script` or `stylesheet` etc. Thank you for all the help :-)